# HTTPS Remote Post?

Tags: c#, ssl, httpcontext

I have a page setup using code from here: http://www.jigar.net/articles/viewhtmlcontent78.aspx in order to post to a remote HTTPS page from my HTTPS page. From what I can tell, this post is being sent in the clear.

Am I misunderstanding? If not, how can I secure the post?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Am I misunderstanding?

If the remote url starts with HTTPS then nothing will be sent in clear text. The entire communication will be done over an encrypted secure channel.

In the aforementioned article they are **not** using HTTPS:

```
myremotepost.Url = "http://www.jigar.net/demo/HttpRequestDemoServer.aspx";
```

Make sure you use it if you want secure communication.

On the other hand this method generates a `<form>` containing all the values in hidden input fields. You should not put any sensitive information such as passwords in thos ehidden fields because anyone that has access to the hosting page could browse the source and see those values. But as far as the transmission of those values to the remote site is concerned, if you use HTTPS, they will be encrypted and not send in clear.

Comment: The site I am posting to is definitely an HTTPS page, I just don't understand at what point the message is encrypted.

Comment: The message is encrypted when the client browser establishes a connection to the remote site. The remote site presents the SSL certificate and the client browser will use the public key of this certificate to encrypt all the communication that it will send to the remote site. The remote site will use the private key of the certificate to decrypt the data. The data is never sent in clear text over the wire. It's how SSL works.

Comment: I am not storing the values on my page but rather getting them from a login form on my page which then checks to see if they are valid on the remote page and then redirects the user through the remote post as if they logged in there. Does this seem secure?

Comment: As I have already stated in my answer this is secure if you are requesting the remote page with HTTPS - if the `action` of the form points to an url starting with `https://`.